# Make changes in the database by drag and drop in react table

Tags: reactjs, html-table, drag-and-drop, react-table-v7

I want to make some changes in the database by drag and drop in the user interface. Actually the data is displayed in tables. the single row has an attribute called priority and the table is ordered according to the priority. now by dragging and dropping the row i have to change the priority. priority swapping function in api is already completed. how can i make drag and drop ,send the data to the back end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd.) library that provides easy implementation of drag and drop feature in tables.

After the user drag and drops a table row it returns the modified rows according to position that you can send to backend.

Comment: Yes it worked. But the project which i am working is with some lower dependencies. so react-beautiful-dnd , react-dnd are not compatible. if you know any libraries which is compatible with lower react version. My react version is 15.6.2